# Node.js Axios GET request error code: ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Hello I can't solve issue with get fresh cookies from few sites let's take on board, maybe someone has idea what is wrong ?

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const tough = require('tough-cookie');
const { AxiosCookieJarSupport } = require('axios-cookiejar-support');

async function getFreshCookies() {
  try {
    const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();
    const config = {
      headers: {},
      timeout: 30 * 1000,
      jar: cookieJar,
    };

    AxiosCookieJarSupport(axios);
    axios.defaults.jar = cookieJar;

    let url = 'https://example.com/';
    let response = await axios.get(url, config);
    let cookies = cookieJar.getCookiesSync(url);

    console.log('Successfully obtained fresh cookies.');
    return cookies;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}

getFreshCookies();
```

Here is error code:

```
cause: Error [ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]: Maximum number of redirects exceeded
      at RedirectableRequest._processResponse (C:\Users\NewSystem\OneDrive\Desktop\node.js learning\test\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:371:24)
      at RedirectableRequest._onNativeResponse (C:\Users\NewSystem\OneDrive\Desktop\node.js learning\test\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:62:10)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:701:27)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) {
    code: 'ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'
  }
```

It's weird because postman return everything correctly but via axios not. I've researched other threads, implemented this and looks like nothing works :(

---

I found solution so editing this post, maybe someone find it usefull in future:

```
    async function getFreshCookies() {
  try {
    const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();

    const instance = axios.create({
      httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
      withCredentials: true, // Enable sending cookies with requests
      maxRedirects: 0, // Disable automatic redirects
      jar: cookieJar, // Attach the cookie jar to the request
    });

    const response = await instance.get('https://example.com', {
      maxRedirects: 0,
      validateStatus: null, // Disable default status code validation
    });


    // Get the cookies from the response headers
    const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];

    console.log('Cookies:', cookies);
    console.log('Response:', response.data);

    // Continue with additional requests using the obtained cookies

    return cookies;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Error: Max redirects exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153849/node-js-error-max-redirects-exceeded)

Comment: I've used max-redirected built in axios module, and set to 3,10,50,100 and doesn't help

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830371/15397231